# Definition of hyperbolic elements and axes in a (limit) group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-groups

I am writing on my master thesis at the moment and it is based on the following article of Fujiwara and Sela: https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.10278

On page 7 they use the terms "hyperbolic element" and their "axes". I searched for a definition on the internet but I only found one for the case of SL2(R).

What is the general definition of these two terms in a group (or if such a general definition does not exist, what is the definition for a limit group etc.)? It would also be nice if you could give me a reference for these definitions because I need a source to cite for my master thesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a group $G$ acts by isometries on a hyperbolic space $X$, there are three kinds of elements. An element is:

1. *elliptic* if it fixes a point of $X$,
2. *hyperbolic* if it fixes exactly two points on the boundary of $X$, denoted $\partial X$, or
3. *parabolic* if it fixes a single point on $\partial X$.

In this setting, $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is particularly important as it is the group of orientation-preserving isometries of the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2$; this is likely why you found the internet searches you did.

For a hyperbolic element, the two points on the boundary are connected by an "axis", which the element acts along by translation.

In geometric group theory we often replace hyperbolic spaces with metric spaces which have hyperbolic-like properties, such as $\delta$-hyperbolic or $\operatorname{CAT}(0)$ spaces. From this point of view, the following definition is often used. An element $g\in G$ is:

1. *elliptic* if it fixes a point of $Y$,
2. *hyperbolic* if there exists $x \in X$ such that
   $d(x, gx) > 0$, or
3. *parabolic* if it is neither elliptic or hyperbolic.

Here we can see that the axis of a hyperbolic element is simply the set of points $\{g^nx\mid x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

---

In the linked article, the groups are limit groups of a fixed hyperbolic group, and the paper analyzes the action of these limit groups on limit trees. These limit trees are hyperbolic-like, so we may apply the above ideas.

Mini-warning - from my understanding, limit trees are not actually trees, but $\mathbb{R}$-trees; see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rips_machine) or [these notes](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Ehjrw2/Talks/Paulin.pdf) of Wilton.

---

For a reference, Bridson and Haefliger's book *Metric spaces of non-positive curvature* ([link](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/bridsonhaefligerx.pdf)) contains much of this, in particular their Chapter 11.6.